# SSIS OLE DB Connection Select Statement Cross Server Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have access to a database that contains a lot of information, and I only import data from one of it's tables into my database where the GUID field of the rows in my one database table matches the GUIDs in one of theirs.

Now in my Data Flow Task, I have an OLE DB Source whereby I want to set the data access mode to a SQL Statement whereby I select all the records where TheirGuid = MyGuid.

The problem I face is that my database and their database are on two different servers; is there any way to achieve this without creating linked servers (whereby they will have access to query my database which is essentially not what I want).
Here is a sample of my table (In Database A, located on Server A):

- Index Number
- Name
- Surname
- Special GUID
- Status

Their table would look like this (In Database B, located on Server B):

- Source ID
- Special GUID
- etc...

Comment: I don't understand.  Linked servers work one way, I.e. you create it on your SQL server with the same details as your SSRS OLE DB settings to query that databases.  They cannot "query over your linked server".

Comment: Essentially to get the data I need via SSIS, I make a connection to their database.  The select is performed on their database with the where clause containing a sub query to my database.  As far as I understand that would imply that the link would be from them to me, not the other way around, although I could be understanding that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You will be doing something along these lines:

```
select
    otherservertable.*
from
    linkserver.otherservertable
left join
    mytable
on
    otherservertable.key = mytable.key
where
    mytable.key is null
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, by making use of SSIS with my OLE DB Source set to their table, I only create the  linked server on my database and use something like the above with their connection source?  Because some how I can't see how that will work since the link is on my side and not their's.

Comment: No,  You will call this in the context of YOUR table, but with the other server set up as a linked server.

Comment: Okay I understand that part now.  Thank you, but this will then not work with my SSIS package as they are the source and my database contains the source condition, and not the other way around.

Comment: 3rd time lucky.....   You will set up the linked server on your server with the OLEDB settings, thereby "having access" to their server within a SQL query or window, but from the context of YOUR server.  So you are then writing a query "as if you are accessing a local table on your database"

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but what I am saying is related to .....achieve this without creating linked servers (whereby they will have access to query my database which is essentially not what I want)......  , as this is not the case.  A linked server to someone else's server does not give them access to your server.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so I create a connection to my db and perform the query through that as a data source.  I was just wondering, should I have Kerberos set up for this? As I keep on getting a 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'' error.

Comment: You need to set the login context.  Under the linked server "Security" option choose "Be made using this security context" and use the username and password supplied to you for the other server.

Comment: I have done that, and they use the same windows login that I use to my server.  So far it doesn't work and I do not have any other logins I can use.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try and add a local <> remote login whereby you specify that 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'' maps to the username you have received.  You can confirm the login does work, right? In Sql, or otherwise.

Comment: I wish I could but I do not have access on the server I am working on to add a local remote login. But I can confirm the login works as I am currently logged in as that user in sql server to their db.